# Using Windows Terminal as default WSL launcher?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-terminal

When I click 'Open linux shell here' inside a directory, it opens the default Microsoft Windows Subsystem for Linux Launcher.

**Is it possible to make Windows Terminal the default WSL launcher?**
So when I click 'Open linux shell here' it opens the Windows Terminal (Ubuntu).

Comment: Just a heads-up that questions on Stack Overflow should be regarding *"specific coding, algorithm, or language problems."* Your question would likely be better suited for [Super User](https://superuser.com), but please be sure to familiarize yourself with that site's rules for posting as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy quick answer. No you can't. However the latest Insider build of Windows ships with Windows Terminal and is in process of becoming the default terminal used. So once that's done, then the answer will be "yes, it will be done automatically". We just need some patience. I would instead recommend taking advantage of the "Open Windows Terminal here" instead and set Ubuntu as your default profile to launch. Similarly, you could run a wt argument to launch Ubuntu that wouldn't rely on switching the default profile. This can be done both inside WT itself on the CLI and in the Command Palette or from a normal CMD/PS window.